# Natural diffeomorphism between $T\mathbb{S}^n\times \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{S}^n\times\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$

Tags: differential-topology, manifolds

I need to show that there is such a diffeomorphism between these spaces. I've tried looking at the 'faces' of elements on both spaces. It went like this: every element in $T\mathbb{S}^n\times \mathbb{R}$ is of the form $([x,i,\vec{v}],r)$, where $x\in\mathbb{S}^n$, $i\in\Gamma$ is an index from the atlas $\Phi$ of $x\in\mathbb{S}^n$, $\vec{v}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $r$ is real.

Elements in $\mathbb{S}^n\times\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ are of the form $(x,\vec{w})$, $x\in\mathbb{S}^n$ and $\vec{w}\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. This is more conveniently written as $\mathbb{S}^n\times\mathbb{R}^{n+1}=\mathbb{S}^n\times\mathbb{R}^{n}\times\mathbb{R}$ so its elements are like $(x,\vec{v},r)$, $\vec{v}\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now, I just take the projection
$$
\begin{array}{llll}
p:&T\mathbb{S}^n\times\mathbb{R}&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{S}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}\\
&([x,i,\vec{v}],r)&\longmapsto& (x,\vec{v},r)
\end{array}
$$

It's not hard to prove that this projection is well defined (since it's defines on the equivalence class $[x,i,\vec{v}]$.

But now, how can I proof that this is a diffeomorphism? It seems obvious that is is invertible but I'm unsure how to proceed on differentiability! My intention is to use the inverse function theorem (since I already have injectivity).

Or is there any easier, more direct way to do this?

Comment: Forget charts and think about actual tangent vectors. The more concrete way of thinking of Micah's answer is that any vector in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ can be uniquely written as a sum of vectors tangent to and normal to the sphere. The normal part is a real number times the position vector.

Comment: How does this allow me to conclude that they are diffeomorphic?

Comment: Write down the map explicitly: $(x,v)\in S^n\times\mathbb R^{n+1}$ maps to $\big(x,v-(v\cdot x)x,v\cdot x\big)$.

Comment: The dot means the usual inner product?

Answer (score 4):

Both of them are naturally diffeomorphic to $T\Bbb{R}^{n+1}|_{S^n}$.

Comment: How can I see this easily like you do?

Comment: Wait, with this do you mean the set of points  $(x_1,...,,x_nx_{n+1})\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2=1$?

Comment: @OhMyGod: yes, that's the idea. The sphere sits inside of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ (as the unit sphere, say). The tangent bundle of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ (which is trivial), restricted to the sphere, can also be seen as the tangent bundle of the sphere summed with its normal bundle.